# How to drag IndexMatch across columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to Excel and I have been using Indexmatch to populate tables, but I found out that I am not able to drag out the function to other columns.

my formula (for Jul 2016):

```
 =INDEX(J:J,(MATCH(S5,B:B,0)))
```

When I drag, I would like it to change to

```
 =INDEX(I:I,(MATCH(S5,B:B,0))).
```

I think there needs to be a 2nd index function in the MATCH but i'm not sure.

Could someone please help me on how to solve it? (also, I am not allowed to reverse the dates on the snapshot table)

I have a very huge screen, so my screenshots are very difficult to view.

But you are the best people, so you'll take time to help me.

[image]

Comment: What's your formula? Are you correctly Anchoring the ranges (with `$`)?

Comment: Yes, but the search column does not change when I drag it across i.e. C:C stays the same even when I drag it.

Comment: Where's your formula???

Comment: Sorry, here is my formula: =INDEX(J:J,(MATCH(S5,B:B,0))) for Jul 2016. I would like it to move change to =INDEX(I:I,(MATCH(S5,B:B,0))). I think there needs to be a 2nd index function in the MATCH but i'm not sure.

Comment: Does it work at all (in your screen shot it shows an error). When you want to drag, do you want the Index to change too??

Comment: Yes, I would like the J:J to switch I:I - H:H etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an anchored part (with `$`), and a moving part (without).

Here is what I would try:

```
=INDEX(J:J,(MATCH($S5,$B:$B,0)))
```

Comment: That would not work as the dates go forward in the data table and the dates go backward in the snapshot table. I ended up using index match and matched both rows and columns to reference the table. Thank you though.

Comment: @VenkataVemuri, good news, it would be appropriate to post this as your own answer, then accept it. The thing is the problematic isn't clear at all in the question, so be very clear in the answer.